A political/spy type of film: the chief assassin knows he's dying (his doctor told him)?
He's a older man with an interesting accent. At one point, he shoots a politician who was (or is) one of his employers; as the politician protests, saying something like, "But I'm a senator?" the assassin counters with his own question: "By whose standards?" before shooting him.
Towards the end, the assassin commits suicide by making a cop shoot him (he first asks the cop whether the latter has a family; when the cop answers in the affirmative, the assassin decides to spare him).
What is the name of this movie?

Sounds like Edge of Darkness
From Wikipedia 

Jedburgh, suffering from an unrelated terminal illness, meets with the Senator and two political advisers who had hired him to handle Craven. They want to spin the Northmoor incident in a positive light. Jedburgh suggests an assassination attempt on the Senator could be an angle to drive Bennett's death out of the headlines
They are pleased with this idea until Jedburgh abruptly pulls out a gun and shoots both advisers and the senator dead.
A young Massachusetts State Police officer nervously enters the Senator's home. Jedburgh points his gun at the officer, but asks if he has a family and kids. When the officer says yes, Jedburgh lowers his gun to face an honorable death. He is immediately shot dead by the officer.




